# didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken is not called in Xcode 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, apple-push-notifications

I build my app on `Xcode 8` with iOS 10 SDK. 
`didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` is not called for iOS 9.3 device, hence iOS 9.3 and bellow devices unable to receive push notifications.
But iOS 10 devices can receive push.
If i build the same app on Xcode 7.3 with iOS 9.3 SDK, then iOS 9 devices can receive push.
So, Im sure that all my settings should be correct.

This is my implementation :

```
// Push notification
if( SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN( @"10.0" ) )
{
    if([application respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)])
    {
        UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound) categories:nil];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];

    }
    else
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes: (UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];
    }


}
else
{
    UNUserNotificationCenter *center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
    center.delegate = self;
    [center requestAuthorizationWithOptions:(UNAuthorizationOptionSound | UNAuthorizationOptionAlert | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge) completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error)
     {
         if( !error )
         {
             [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
         }

     }];
}


- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {

NSString * tokenAsString = [[[deviceToken description]
                             stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"]]
                            stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];

}



- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error {

DLog(@"app didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError: %@", error.description);
}
```

Comment: delete and install your app in your device once and check

Comment: Anyway your app will not register for push notifications in iOS7 because the method `registerForRemoteNotifications` is called in iOS 8 and 9 which respond to `registerUserNotificationSettings`.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you using deprecated method ?? `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:`

When I removed it

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge)categories:nil]];
```

and used

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
```

I got token from APNs.

Comment: I removed it and tried. But still not not getting token. Did you tried on xcode 8 and ios 9.3 device?

Comment: @ANANTHAKRISHNANKG The OP defined 3 cases for iOS7, 8/9 and 10. The method `registerForRemoteNotificationTypes` is only used in iOS7 where the actual methods are not available.

Comment: @vadian he is trying in iOS9.3 and 10 I guess.. That's why I said `registerForRemoteNotificationTypes` is deprecated .

Comment: @vadian Yes, actually, I just use my existing code and just add mnew code sets for iOS 10. Thats why you can see deprecated methods.

Comment: @ANANTHAKRISHNANKG No, the code checks the system version and runs different code for different versions. The deprecated code is never used in iOS 9 and 10.

Comment: @vadian Yeah I got your point. you are saying about  `if( SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN( @"10.0" ) )`, right ??

Comment: @ANANTHAKRISHNANKG Yes and also the line `if  ... respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)`. iOS7 does not respond to that selector

Comment: @ANANTHAKRISHNANKG what you mean by this "Did you changed the version in General tab and tried"...

Comment: @sajaz I mean the deployment target version.

Comment: @ANANTHAKRISHNANKG current deployment target is ios 8. How that matters?

Answer (score 1):

You need to call registerForNotifications method from didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.

```
 func registerForNotifications(){
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
            center.delegate = self
            center.requestAuthorization(options:[.alert,.sound,.badge]) { (granted, error) in
                if granted{
                    UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
                }else{
                    print("Notification permission denied.")

                }
            }

        } else {
            // For iOS 9 and Below
            let type: UIUserNotificationType = [.alert,.sound,.badge];
            let setting = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: type, categories: nil);
            UIApplication.shared.registerUserNotificationSettings(setting);
            UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        }
    }

 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        let token = String(format: "%@", deviceToken as CVarArg).trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet(charactersIn: "<>")).replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")
        print(token)
    }


extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate{
    @available(iOS 10.0, *)
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,  willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler   completionHandler: @escaping (_ options:   UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        print("Handle push from foreground”)

        let info = ((notification.request.content.userInfo as NSDictionary).value(forKey: "aps") as! NSDictionary)
        if let type = info.value(forKey: "type") as? Int{
            if type == 0 {   // notification arrive
                handlePush(apsDict: (notification.request.content.userInfo as NSDictionary))
            }
        }
    }
    @available(iOS 10.0, *)
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        print("Handle push from background or closed")

        let info = ((response.notification.request.content.userInfo as NSDictionary).value(forKey: "aps") as! NSDictionary)
        if let type = info.value(forKey: "type") as? Int{
            if type == 0 {   // notification arrive
                handlePush(apsDict: (response.notification.request.content.userInfo as NSDictionary))
            }
        }
    }
}
```